# I want Win + Alt + D functionality but as a clickable shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, calendar, popups

Like the title says, I want to be able to invoke the calendar pop up but rather than using a keyboard shortcut, I want it to be from a click. Reason I'm not just clicking on the clock is because I want to have this functionality from my Rainmeter date and hide the system tray clock.
I'm assuming the keyboard shortcut is just invoking a command anyway so is there someway for me to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What calendar? What is CTRL-ALT-D?

Comment: @music2myear - By default it does nothing, CTRL+ALT+D is not a shortcut that by default, does anything on Windows.

Comment: @music2myear: CTRL+ALT+D calls up the agenda, same as clicking on the date in the traybar.

Comment: @music2myear not CTRL but the Windows button + alt + D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a combination of keys to be combined into one keyboard macro.
To build up the macro, enter the following once:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - selects the Windows system tray
- <kbd>Arrow right</kbd> - count how many presses are required to reach the calendar
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> - open the calendar

You may use for this the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Say that you needed to press ten times <kbd>Arrow right</kbd> to arrive at the calendar
and that you want <kbd>F12</kbd> as your hotkey.
Use the following AutoHotkey script:

```
F12:: Send, {LWin Down}b{LWin Up}{Right 10}{Enter}
```

To use another hotkey than <kbd>F12</kbd>, see the AutoHotkey documentation :
[Hotkeys - Definition & Usage](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

To use no key at all, put the `.ahk` file (or a link to it) on the desktop,
but take out the hotkey. The file will then become a script that is executed
by a double-click:

```
Send, {LWin Down}b{LWin Up}{Right 10}{Enter}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green `H` icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Why not just put win+alt+D in autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

StartAllBack offers this feature in it's settings go to taskbar > corner icons open: > windows 10 flyouts if possible

Comment: Please improve your answer by giving some features here.